# css columns in left to right order

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

is there any amount of JS that would make css columns display the results from left to right as opposed to up to down?

heres the resource I found on css columns: http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/

the code

```
-webkit-column-count: 5;
-webkit-column-gap:   0px;
-moz-column-count:    5;
-moz-column-gap:      0px;
column-count:         5;
column-gap:           0px;
```

this is how it currently displays
http://jsfiddle.net/KJ7F9/3/

This is how I would like it to display
http://jsfiddle.net/KJ7F9/2/

Comment: Not with the "columns" property, because the number of blocks per column is variable

Comment: so really, the only way to reproduce this the way I want is to use a library like masonry or do custom JS that positions each div absolutely with specific left / top ya?!?!